# How to import a js file to another one in react using CDN with babel compiler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, babeljs, export

I am using react CDN and babel compiler and I want to import a js file to another but i have this problem:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at <anonymous>:3:15
at Kbe (transformScriptTags.ts:99:10)
at n (transformScriptTags.ts:173:9)
at s (transformScriptTags.ts:204:11)
at Jbe.t.forEach.e.src.o.onreadystatechange (transformScriptTags.ts:121:9)
```

I know my question is not clear, so this is the complete codes

index.html:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>React</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
import Hello from "./source"
let root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Hello />);
```

source.js:

```
export default function Hello() {
    return (<h1>Hello</h1>)
}
```

So, how to fix this problem?

I expect that we need to use "require" but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using the global scope, like how `ReactDOM` is available for use:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>React</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script type="text/babel" src="js/Hello.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then in source.js:

```
function Hello() {
    return (<h1>Hello</h1>)
}
```

Will put `Hello` in the global scope, which then can be consumed by `index.js`:

```
let root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Hello />);
```